# How to get the latest cms posts data in a gatsby built project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I've build a static website with gatsby and it workes fine . The problem is When I change the posts title and body in contentful cms and refresh the website it doesn't fetch the latest updated version of posts.
How can I always get the latest posts from a cms like contentful ? Do I have to rebuild the whole project and then redeploy the built files to hosting service everytime there is an update in cms posts ?

Comment: you need to rebuild the project and then redeploy the built files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Gatsby is a [static site generator](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/14/what-is-a-static-site-generator-and-3-ways-to-find-the-best-one/) so you have to rebuild after changes in your CMS. Where are you hosting? [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) is a hosting platform that does this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said, Gatsby is a static site generator and it needs to re-fetch the data in the build time, so you'll need to redeploy the site. There's an automated way, however, to achieve this, called [webhook](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/cloud/docs/webhook/).

A webhook is a way for an application to notify another application when a new event has occurred in real-time. In your case, once your data has been updated, deleted, or created, the webhook will trigger into the server the new deploy.

Depending on your host, the webhook is automatically set (like Netlify, because every change is a branch that is merged in a pull-request once the deploy occurs) or needs to be built from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the info on webhooks will definitely look into it